# Inserting document into CosmosDB with C#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to insert a new document to a cosmos database running locally with SQLAPI in the Cosmos Emulator. Selecting documents works fine but when I try to insert with below code I get the following error:

Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 1003; ActivityId: 10e20d81-559a-47b3-8eef-021ce4138279; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]}

Code:

```
async Task<Product> IProductRepository.Add(Product product)
        {
            var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("Invertory", "Products");
            product.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            product.Category = new Category() { Name = "test" };
            var x = await container.UpsertItemAsync<Product>(product);
            return product;
        }
```

It seems that the recourse (database) I try to reach not exists, but when I do a query with the same database and container and with the following code I get the expected results.

```
async Task<Product> IProductRepository.Get(string Id)
        {            
            var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("Inventory", "Products");
            var iterator = (from p in container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>()
                            where p.Id.Equals(Id)
                            select p).ToFeedIterator();

            return iterator.HasMoreResults ? (await iterator.ReadNextAsync()).First() : null;
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems to be a typo in function "IProductRepository.Add". **Invertory** should be **Inventory**

Comment: OMG, I'm looking at this for hours, and missed it. Thanks!

Comment: @gkulshrestha Can you post your answer ?

Comment: @Jason posted my answer. Just thought there wasn't much to the answer so didn't post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in function "IProductRepository.Add". **Invertory** should be **Inventory**.